# Nunit Test Case Discovery is taking over 13.5 min to discover 108 test cases when using TestCaseSource

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, nunit

Having issues I cant seem to solve the Nunit test discovery is taking over 13.5 min to discover test using the TestCaseSource attribute.  Anytime a change happens on the code it takes over 13 min to discover the test when I go to debug and run the test from Test explorer.

Have anyone dealt with this with any code examples or settings that might be given. I've read the documentation and haven't figured out what else to change other then that this maybe cause by filters that are being sent for test discovery.
Here is my set up
VS 2022
NUnit adapter : 4.5
Nunit 3.13.3

Comment: This obviously depends on what the method/property referenced by the `TestCaseSource` attribute does. Difficult to tell without seeing this code.